# Random number with user defined range

Tags: swift, random, range

I am teaching myself Swift and am stuck with a Random function.

What I want to achieve: User is able to specify the min and max of the Range.

Code I have now for the button, where I believe I am declaring the text as an integer:

```
@IBAction func generateNumbers(sender: AnyObject) {

    let minRange:Int? = Int(lowValue.text!)
    let maxRange:Int? = Int(highValue.text!)

    func randomNumber(range: Range<Int> = minRange...maxRange) -> Int {
        let min = range.startIndex
        let max = range.endIndex
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min
    }
}
```

Obviously minRange and maxRange aren't valid integers for the Range, I am just wondering where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You need to unwrap minRange and maxRange and it'll work.

Comment: Okay I'll look into unwrapping. Thank you very much!

Comment: "Optionals". Very important. :) Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have identified, your `minRange` and `maxRange` are [*Optionals*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).  They need to be `Int`, not `Int?` in order to form the range.

Also, you should avoid using `!` to unwrap the text fields, just in case they're `nil`.

If you have some reasonable defaults for `minRange` and `maxRange` (such as `1` and `10`), you could use the *nil coalescing operator* to unwrap your text fields and replace the values with defaults if the text fields can't be converted to an `Int`:

```
@IBAction func generateNumbers(sender: AnyObject) {

    let minRange = Int(lowValue.text ?? "") ?? 1
    let maxRange = Int(highValue.text ?? "") ?? 10

    func randomNumber(range: Range<Int>) -> Int {
        let min = range.startIndex
        let max = range.endIndex
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min
    }

    // test
    let results = randomNumber(minRange...maxRange)
    self.field1.text = String(results)
}
```

Note:  The compiler is **not** happy with using the values `minRange` and `maxRange` to set the default value for `range`, so I added them to the call of `randomNumber`.

---

There is another potential *gotcha* here as well.  You can't form a range if `minRange` is larger than `maxRange`, so you should check for that as well:

```
var minRange = Int(lowValue.text ?? "") ?? 1
var maxRange = Int(highValue.text ?? "") ?? 10
if minRange > maxRange {
    // Swap 'em
    (minRange, maxRange) = (maxRange, minRange)
}
```

---

Why even torture yourself in creating the range anyway?  Since `randomNumber` is declared inside of `generateNumbers` you can just use `minRange` and `maxRange`:

```
@IBAction func generateNumbers(sender: AnyObject) {

    var minRange = Int(lowValue.text ?? "") ?? 1
    var maxRange = Int(highValue.text ?? "") ?? 10
    if minRange > maxRange {
        // Swap 'em
        (minRange, maxRange) = (maxRange, minRange)
    }

    func randomNumber() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxRange - minRange))) + minRange
    }

    //test
    let results = randomNumber()
    self.field1.text = String(results)
}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice and simple way to do it, thank you. However, it kept coming up with an error requesting I insert a ; separator, which didn't work either.

Comment: Which line specifically requested the `;`?

Comment: Actually just copy pasting your code in only resulted in an error at run. So I'm probably doing something wrong. Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/u‌​sr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: Make sure all of your `@IBOutlets` are wired up.

Comment: Check out my latest update.  You don't even need to bother creating the range.

Comment: The errors were being cause by something locally, not your code. I selected it as the most appropriate answer as your first suggestion works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

### You are almost there

The problem is that

```
let minRange:Int? = Int(lowValue.text!)
let maxRange:Int? = Int(highValue.text!)
```

are defined as optionals.

While here

```
func randomNumber(range: Range<Int> = minRange...maxRange) -> Int {
```

you need `minsRange` and `maxRange` to be non optional.

So you could use the `guard let` statement to safely perform the needed unwrappings

```
@IBAction func generateNumbers(sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let
        lowText = lowValue.text,
        highText = highValue.text,
        minRange = Int(lowText),
        maxRange = Int(highText)
    else {
        print("Couldn't find valid integers inside lowValue and highValue UITextFields. So I'm giving up...")
        return
    }

    func randomNumber(range: Range<Int> = minRange...maxRange) -> Int {
        let min = range.startIndex
        let max = range.endIndex
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min
    }
}
```

### Invoking randomNumber

Of course don't forget to finally invoke your function `randomNumber(1...10)`

### Update

```
@IBAction func generateNumbers(sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let
        lowText = lowValue.text,
        highText = highValue.text,
        minRange = Int(lowText),
        maxRange = Int(highText)
        else {
            print("Couldn't find valid integers inside lowValue and highValue UITextFields. So I'm giving up...")
            return
    }

    let result = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(minRange - maxRange))) + minRange

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much I will try this now! :)

Comment: Unfortunately I receive this error: Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: @PeterG: interesting error. I think the problem is about the default parameter value used into `randomNumber`. Infact providing an explicitt value `randomNumber(1...100)` seems to solve the error. If you want I can provide you a workaround.

Comment: I can get it working in Playground like this: let lowValue = "10"
let highValue = "50"

    let minRange:Int? = Int(lowValue)
    let maxRange:Int? = Int(highValue)

func randomNumber(range: Range<Int> = minRange!...maxRange!) -> Int {
    let min = range.startIndex
    let max = range.endIndex
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + min
}

let results = randomNumber()

Comment: @PeterG: it is working only because you removed the parent function (which seems to be the problem). In your code you are using `!` which I suggest you to avoid. Just take a look at the updated section in my answer.

Comment: Okay thank you! The code seems to be fine :) I think there must be a problem when attempting to run it though because I keep getting that odd error I stated previously. Thanks so much for your help, time to reset my mac I think hehe